# This word with a lot of past tenses

Tags: word, no-computers

This interesting word is full of past

> Starts with a past tense verb.
>
> Add a letter at the end and you have a different past tense verb.
>
> Then add more letters at the end  and you get yet another past tense
>   verb.
>
> Remove one letter from this word and - you guessed it - you have yet
>   another past tense verb.

So what is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about

> ran - rang - ranged - raged

Comment: there is another word which is also a past tense of a word that is a past tense of another word. Can you find it?

Comment: @DEEM Felted! :p

Comment: Hmm. Founded too I guess

Comment: @DEEM Also sawed...